# How to append comma separated value dynamically in groovy

Tags: groovy

I've comma separated values which I want to iterate and append the value dynamically like below:

```
def statusCode = '1001,1002,1003'
```

Output should look like this:

```
[item][code]=1001|[item][code]=1002|[item][code]=1003
```

If statusCode has only two value. For example:

```
def statusCode = '1001,1002'
```

Then output should be

```
[item][code]=1001|[item][code]=1002
```

I tried something like below since I'm new to groovy not sure how can achieve this with some best approach:

```
    def statusCode= '1001,1002,1003'
    String[] myData = statusCode.split(",");
    def result
    for (String s: myData) {
        result <<= "[item][code]="+s+"|"
    }
    System.out.println("result :" +result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect` and `join` to simplify the code:

```
def result = statusCode.split(',').collect{"[item][code]=$it"}.join('|')
```

That returns `[item][code]=1001|[item][code]=1002|[item][code]=1003`